# c# sharp game. out of range error

Tags: c#

I am somewhat new to c#, and am getting an error message. I am trying to recreate a program that was posted on youtube at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8XQ9x-7yYk

I seem to be running into some problems. It is saying that it is an out of range error. I've been trying different methods to fix the issue and I cant seem to do anything.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
     public Form3()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string word = "";
    List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
    int amount = 0;

    enum BodyParts
    {
        Head,
        Left_Eye,
        Right_Eye,
        Mouth,
        Right_Arm,
        Left_Arm,
        Body,
        Left_Leg,
        Right_Leg,

    }
    void drawhangpost()
    {
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Brown, 10);
        g.DrawLine(p, new Point(130, 218), new Point(130, 5));
        g.DrawLine(p, new Point(135, 5), new Point(65, 5));
        g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 0), new Point(60, 50));
        //DrawBodyPart(BodyParts.Head);//just for show
        //DrawBodyPart(BodyParts.Left_Eye);
        //DrawBodyPart(BodyParts.Right_Eye);
        //DrawBodyPart(BodyParts.Mouth);
        //DrawBodyPart(BodyParts.Right_Arm);
        //DrawBodyPart(BodyParts.Left_Arm);
        //DrawBodyPart(BodyParts.Body);
        //DrawBodyPart(BodyParts.Left_Leg);
        //DrawBodyPart(BodyParts.Right_Leg);
        //MessageBox.Show(GetRandomWord());
    }
    void DrawBodyPart(BodyParts bp)
    {
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);
        if (bp == BodyParts.Head)
            g.DrawEllipse(p, 40, 50, 40, 40);
        else if (bp == BodyParts.Left_Eye)
        {
            SolidBrush s = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            g.FillEllipse(s, 50, 60, 5, 5);
        }
        else if (bp == BodyParts.Right_Eye)
        {
            SolidBrush s = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            g.FillEllipse(s, 63, 60, 5, 5);
        }
        else if (bp == BodyParts.Mouth)
        {
            g.DrawArc(p, 50, 60, 20, 20, 45, 90);
        }
        else if (bp == BodyParts.Body)
            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 90), new Point(60, 170));
        else if (bp == BodyParts.Left_Arm)
            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 100), new Point(30, 85));
        else if (bp == BodyParts.Right_Arm)
            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 100), new Point(90, 85));
        else if (bp == BodyParts.Left_Leg)
            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 170), new Point(30, 190));
        else if (bp == BodyParts.Right_Leg)
            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(60, 170), new Point(90, 190));
    }
    void MakeLables()
    {
        word = GetRandomWord();
        char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
        int between = 330 / chars.Length - 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            labels.Add(new Label());
            labels[i].Location = new Point((i * between) + 10, 80);
            labels[i].Text = "_";
            labels[i].Parent = groupBox2;
            labels[i].BringToFront();
            labels[i].CreateControl();
        }
        label1.Text = "Word Length: " + (chars.Length - 1).ToString();
    }
    string GetRandomWord()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string wordList = wc.DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tom25/Hangman/master/wordlist.txt");
        string[] words = wordList.Split('\n');
        Random ran = new Random();
        return words[ran.Next(0, words.Length - 1)];
    }
    private void form3_shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drawhangpost();
        MakeLables();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char letter = textBox1.Text.ToLower().ToCharArray()[0];
        if (!char.IsLetter(letter))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You can only submit letters.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        if (word.Contains(letter))
        {
            char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
            {
                if (letters[i] == letter)
                    labels[i].Text = letter.ToString();//Line gives out of rage error 
            }
            foreach (Label l in labels)
            if (l.Text == "_") return;
            MessageBox.Show("You have won", "Congrats");
            ResetGame();
        }
        else
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("The letter you guessed is wrong", "Sorry");
            label2.Text += " " + letter.ToString() + ",";
            DrawBodyPart((BodyParts)amount);
            amount++;
            if (amount == 9)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry but you lost, the word was " + word);
                ResetGame();
            }
        }
    }
    void ResetGame()
    {
        amount = 0;// testing not sure
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(panel1.BackColor);
        GetRandomWord();
        MakeLables();
        drawhangpost();
        label2.Text = "Missed: ";
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == word)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Have won", "Congrats");
            ResetGame();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The word you guest was wrong", "Sorry");
            DrawBodyPart((BodyParts)amount);
            amount++;
            if (amount == 9)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry but you lost, the word was " + word);
                ResetGame();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what line produces the error?

Comment: labels[i].Text = letter.ToString();

Comment: how do I go about defing lables

Comment: actually, you do have labels defined -- it's a list.

Comment: Ive been told that some of the code should create a compile error too             this code in particular:                                                                                              if (letters[i] == letter)

Comment: The error you are getting is pretty self explanatory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx . If you step through your code, it should be pretty apparent where your mistake is.

Comment: Believe me i'm trying, i just not seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are making your labels, you are missing the last one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        labels.Add(new Label());
        labels[i].Location = new Point((i * between) + 10, 80);
        labels[i].Text = "_";
        labels[i].Parent = groupBox2;
        labels[i].BringToFront();
        labels[i].CreateControl();
    }
```

The loop stops when i is less than one less than the length of the word. If you word is 6 characters long, your labels will stop at index 4 because 5 is not less than 6 - 1. Change it to <= or just < and drop the -1.

When you loop through the labels to set the text to the letter, you are doing it correctly:

```
if (word.Contains(letter))
    {
        char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (letters[i] == letter)
                labels[i].Text = letter.ToString();//Line gives out of rage error 
        }
        foreach (Label l in labels)
        if (l.Text == "_") return;
        MessageBox.Show("You have won", "Congrats");
        ResetGame();
    }
```

So, if your word is 6 letters long, when you guess the last letter in the word i will be 5, which you didn't create a label for, and it fails.

Comment: The program is making the correct amount of lables without modifying the code. If I change it "<=" i am getting one less.

Comment: I don't see how that can be true. Are you sure you only made that change?

Comment: if i change the code the following code`for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length -1; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i <= chars.Length -1; i++)` i get one less label

Comment: Generally speaking you should write it as for(int i=0; i < chars.Length; i++) but the other form should be logically equivalent. Oh! your between might be wrong because you're subtracting 1 from the length. Try changing that line as well to be: int between = 330 / chars.Length; Using a debugger, you should look at the length of your labels list after that loop runs. You should have the same length as your word. If that is true, then the missing label is probably being placed incorrectly within the form (hence the suggestion to change the between calculation).

Comment: to be honest. I don't follow you completely. The initial problem was that there was an out of range error being created. Will any of these changes stop an out of range exception from occuring?

Comment: Yes. The initial suggestion of changing the conditions of your for loop in MakeLabels will fix the out of range exception. You are saying that when you do that you end up with one less label, which can't be true. So, your problem after your out of range exception was fixed is that there is some kind of behavior happening that makes you feel like you have one less label than you should. I promise you that if you made the change suggested in this answer you will not get the out of range exception anymore.

Comment: I tried that code for`(int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)` like you said and I get an error message.I think the problem that is happening is that there are two arrays. One for **labels** and one for **letters**. They are supposed to be equal but they aren't for some reason. So i need to set them to the same value

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was completely wrong.

Here is the problem.  labels is a List of type Label.  The list length is defined in MakeLabels(), here:

```
char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
...
for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length - 1; i++)
{
        labels.Add(new Label());
        ...
        labels[i].Text = "_";
        ...
```

So, the list length is chars.Length - 1

But then in your button1_Click function, you have:

```
        char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (letters[i] == letter)
                labels[i].Text = letter.ToString();
         ...
```

Here, you i can go up to letters.Length, which is greater than the length of the labels list.  You should have as many labels as potential letters if you're going to assign a letter to labels[i].Text (at the same index as letters[i]).  This means you should change MakeLabels to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
```

Comment: I've re-written my answer.